# Telegram bot -python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

i want to write a code for a telegram bot, where i can connect and see a "dashboard" and "kpi" sheet on a google sheet, however i keep getting this error;

```
"PS C:\Users\ASUS> & C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.12.exe    c:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/philbot.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\philbot.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
     File "c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\philbot.py", line 41, in main
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'
```

Below is the code;

```
# CODE start
import telegram
from telegram import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import gspread

# Telegram bot token
TOKEN = 'xxxxxyyyyyy'

# Google Sheets credentials
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/credentials.json'  # Specify the path to your     credentials JSON file
spreadsheet_id = 'yyyyxxxxxxx'

# Authenticate with Google Sheets API
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Function to fetch data from Google Sheets
def get_sheet_data(sheet_name):
    gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
    worksheet = sheet.worksheet(sheet_name)
    return worksheet.get_all_values()

# Command handler for starting the bot
def start(bot, update):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Dashboard", callback_data='dashboard')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("KPI", callback_data='kpi')]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)

# Callback handler for button presses
def button(bot, update):
    query = update.callback_query
    sheet_name = query.data
    data = get_sheet_data(sheet_name)
    message = '\n'.join(['\t'.join(row) for row in data])
    query.edit_message_text(text=message)

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i was trying to have 2 buttons in my telegram bot, where if pushed connects to the sheets with the same name and show me the table there, however getting an error

Comment: What errror? You only tell the line number of the error, not the actual error message.

Comment: hi..this is the error i receive; "TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'"